# Is there any 3d mindmapping software available? Preferrably with developer API..?

Tags: 3d-graphics, mind-mapping

As the title states:

**Is there any 3d mindmapping software available? Preferrably with developer API..?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[3D Topicscape](http://www.topicscape.com/)**, is a Personal Information Manager that provides a template loosely based on mind-mapping or concept mapping. It presents the mind map as a 3D scene.

[image]

*3D Topicscape is shareware, try before you buy.*

Comment: Nicely done! However I want to be able to freely move/form the objects...

Comment: @ropstah - you can use FreeMind and then export the mind-map into 3D Topicsacpe, if it helps: http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Import_and_export_to_other_applications#To_3D_Topicscape

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind! is [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

There isn't a developer API as far as I know, but it is free and [open source](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Development#Getting_started_as_a_developer), so you can get the source code and do a lot more than an API would probably allow.

Comment: I actually downloaded this and it's very intuitive! However I really like some more freehand: sizing objects, -more- objects (custom preferrably) and really 3d space :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I haven't seen any so far. But then again, I don't use them much.

I'm not sure actually how that would even look like (not very clearly).

In any case, here is a [list of free and proprietary mind mapping software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mind_mapping_software), many of them have screenshots attached, so check it out ... see, maybe you'll find something you like.